# Computing maximum of an expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the maximum of the expression? 
$$x_1x_2x_3+x_2x_3x_4+\cdots+x_{2011}x_{2012}x_{2013}$$
If $x_1,x_2,..,x_{2013} \in [0,\infty)$, $x_1+x_2+\cdots + x_{2013}=2013$

Comment: What are your own thoughts on the problem?

Comment: @Eckhard blurred thoughts. What are your own thoughts on the problem? It's a middle school question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Compare with

$$ ( x_1 + x_4 + \ldots + x_{2011} ) ( x_2 + x_5 + \ldots + x_{2012} ) ( x_3 + x_6 + \ldots + x_{2013} ) $$

Comment: This is the right way.