Maximum value of $a_{1}a_{2}+a_{2}a_{3}+\cdots +a_{7}{a_{8}}$

If $a_{1},a_{2},\cdots \cdots ,a_{8}$ all are non negative numbers and $a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots +a_{8}=16$. Then maximum of $\displaystyle a_{1}a_{2}+a_{2}a_{3}+\cdots +a_{7}a_{8}$

What I try : $\displaystyle a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}\cdots a_{8}\leq \bigg(\frac{a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{8}}{8}\bigg)^8$
$\displaystyle a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{8}\leq 2^8=64$
Now $\displaystyle \frac{a_{1}a_{2}+a_{2}a_{3}+\cdots +a_{7}a_{8}+a_{8}a_{1}}{8}\geq \bigg(a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{8}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{4}}$
But this will gave minimum of expression, plz have a look on that problem, Thanks

A solution on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1790957p11847151

Something similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/445338/42969

$2^8=256$ not $64$

It's 64. Assume you have some optimal eight values. Transfer $a_1$ to $a_3$. That is:

Add its value to $a_3$. This increases $a_2a_3$ and thus the sum of products by $a_2a_1$.

Set $a_1$ to $0$. This decreases $a_1a_2$ and thus the sum of products by $a_1a_2$.


That increase and decrease cancel out, and the enlarged $a_3$ has the chance to enlarge the sum of products due to $a_3a_4$.
Then likewise transfer $a_2$ to $a_4$, and so on. You end up with only $a_7$ and $a_8$ being nonzero. And then of course you maximize by making them equal, i.e., $a_7=a_8=8$, and the sum of products is 64.
We started with an optimum, only made changes that didn't make it worse, and ended up with 64. So 64 is optimum.
